# Concatenate two typed variadic template packs

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates, template-meta-programming

Consider this struct

```
template<std::size_t... a>
struct A{};
```

How can I concatenate two typed variadic template arguments?

```
concat<A<1,2,3>, A<4,5,6,7>> // should be of type A<1,2,3,4,5,6,7>
```

Comment: Basically, you can declare `template<typename Arg1, typename Arg2> struct concat_impl;` and specialize it via `template<size_t... a, size_t... b> struct concat_impl<A<a...>, A<b...>> { using type = A<a...,b...>;};` then write an alias `template<typename Arg1, typename Arg2> using concat = typename concat_impl<Arg1,Arg2>::type;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can implement this with a specialization that handles instantiations of `A`.

```
template<typename...>
struct concat_impl;   // just a declaration, to allow for specializations

template<std::size_t... s1, std::size_t... s2>
struct concat_impl<A<s1...>, A<s2...>> {        // specialize   
    using type = A<s1..., s2...>;               // concatenate
};
```

and a convenience alias to avoid having to say `typename` everywhere.

```
template<typename A1, typename A2>
using concat = typename concat_impl<A1,A2>::type;
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/sY8jP4)